# Excel offset/match avoid duplicate

Tags: excel, match, offset, excel-2016

I have 2 columns, 
B2-B21 have titles, C2-C21 have values.

In E2-E6 I am using Large to find the 5 largest values in the C2-C21 range. 
In D2-D6 I am using 
=OFFSET(INDEX($B$2:$B$21,MATCH($C2,$B$2:$B$21,0)), 0, -1)

To get me the associated title. However, because their could be 2 or 3 items with the same count in E2-E6 it currently gives me the same name for both if they are duplicate.

Is the a mix between large/offset that I could utilize?
I tried the below but this fell into the same trap of returning the duplicate title.

=OFFSET(INDEX($B$2:$B$21,MATCH(LARGE(B3:B21, 1),$B$2:$B$21,0)), 0, -1)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36660620/select-top-n-values-from-excel-row/36661537#36661537

Comment: Looks like it would solve the problem but it exceeds my excel knowledge, not making much sense out of the formula to adapt it. 
I tried the below to no avail

=INDEX($B$2:$B$21,,--RIGHT(SMALL(RANK.EQ($C$2:$C$21,$C$2:$C$21,0)*10^5+COLUMN($C$2:$C$21),COLUMNS($B$2:$B$21)),5))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Formulas:

`E2` downwards:

```
=LARGE($C$2:$C$21,ROW(A1))
```

`F2` downwards:

```
{=INDEX($B$1:$B$21,--RIGHT(SMALL(RANK.EQ($C$2:$C$21,$C$2:$C$21,0)*10^5+ROW($C$2:$C$21),ROWS($1:1)),5))}
```

The formula in `F2` is an array formula. Input it into the cell without the curly brackets. Then press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to confirm. The curly brackets will then appear automatically.

Comment: Perfect thankyou :) I can stop pulling what little hair i have left out now :)